# Images won't display for leaflet-measure plugin in R powered custom visual for PowerBI

Tags: r, powerbi-embedded, r-leaflet

We are trying to create a custom visual using leaflet for PowerBI to use in our application. The visual works perfectly on the PowerBI desktop, however, when the visual is uploaded to PowerBI embedded, the images for plugins such as leaflet-measure are not loaded. The functions in the plugin such as measurements etc., however, works as intended.

Originally, the images for the leaflet-measure plugin did not show on the PowerBI desktop as well. We reached out to the custom visual team at Microsoft and they suggested to use the 'base64' encoding of the images in the file 'leaflet-measure.css'. This made the plugins to start working on PBI desktop, but, publishing online on PowerBI embedded still has the issue with the images like 'rulers.png' etc. not being able to render correctly.

Here's how the Leaflet measure looks on PBI desktop
[image]

The leaflet measure when published on PowerBI.com or embedded
[image]

Can you please help so that the images are rendered properly when the custoembedded?s uploaded to PowerBI.com or embedded ?

Comment: is there any code you can share?

Answer (score 0):

So, we got back to Microsoft tech support and they said that while they do support custom interactive visuals based on R, any networking on server side (from R) is blocked due to security and privacy reasons.

Hence, if it tried to load an image from R via net, it will not work. 
Since the images from the plugins are plain image files rendered onto the leaflet map, it might not display when creating an leaflet based R custom visual.